# Chrome flag #filling-across-affiliated-websites vs #filling-across-grouped-sites

Tags: google-chrome, grouping, credentials, flags

I was reading on the topic of [Site Affiliation at Chrome for Developers](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/identity/site-affiliation) to be able to share login credentials across affiliated sites.

In that article they mention the following flag `filling-across-affiliated-websites` including a link:

[chrome://flags#filling-across-affiliated-websites](https://chrome://flags#filling-across-affiliated-websites)

The link leads to nothing in my Chrome Version 122.0.6261.129, but I found a very similar flag named `filling-across-grouped-sites`:

[chrome://flags/#filling-across-grouped-sites](https://chrome://flags/#filling-across-grouped-sites)

I tried to search on the topic and particularly that new flag `filling-across-grouped-sites` but I hardly find any information.

Since the post is quite old (2021) I assume that this feature was adopted and enabled by default in later Chrome browsers but in the process they changed the name of the flag. Is that the right conclusion?

If yes, does it also mean that passwords will be shared now between two correctly associated websites by default without any prerequisites like the user enabling any flags?